# How can I connect to Remote Linux Nodes on which Hadoop is installed using Apache Nifi instance installed on my local Windows Box?

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, apache-nifi

I have installed Apache nifi 1.1.1 on My Windows Local System. How can  I connect to Remote Linux Nodes on which Hadoop is installed using Apache Nifi instance installed on my local Windows Box?
Also How can  I perform data migration activity on Remote Linux Nodes on which Hadoop is installed using these local instance of Nifi?
I have enabled Kerberos on these Remote Hadoop Cluster.

Comment: You'll likely need all your Hadoop XML configuration files, and the Hadoop client libraries. Otherwise, have you tried a HdfsPut processor? What happens when you do?

Comment: Or why can't you install Nifi into the cluster? That would make more sense to me

Comment: When I installed nifi on one of the hadoop cluster node I got following error:$./nifi-1.1.1/bin/nifi.sh run

nifi.sh: JAVA_HOME not set; results may vary

Java home:
NiFi home: /root/nifi-1.1.1

Bootstrap Config File: /root/nifi-1.1.1/conf/bootstrap.conf

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/nifi/bootstrap/RunNiFi : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: Then the error is that Nifi is not installed correctly and its not a Hadoop related issue. Read the errors. 1) Java home isn't set 2) You're running Java 8 but Nifi doesn't like that

Comment: @cricket_007 Also I have tried HdfsPut processor. But that also needs kerberos principal details in nifi.properties. But as I told you I have installed nifi on my local . so the question is How do i connect to the remote Hadoop cluster using the kerberos details?

Comment: Do you have a keytab? Is the windows box in the trusted kerberos environment? Are the users and groups in Windows in sync with the kerberos system? So many variables at play and your Nifi seems to be just crashing on start

Comment: I keytab and principals for kerberos enabled on hadoop server , not on windows

Comment: @cricket_007 But Can I connect to remote cluster using local windows nifi instance?

Comment: Simply put... Yes, you can. It's only a network socket connection. The entire configuration details of your setup are missing, though, so it is difficult to help more than that.

Answer (score 2):

The "Unsupported major.minor version" is because Apache NiFi 1.x requires Java 8, and you tried to start it with a Java 7 JVM. You could install a Java 8 JDK just for NiFi to use, and leave all the Hadoop stuff using Java 7, and you can set NiFi's JAVA_HOME in bin/nifi-env.sh:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk1.8.0/
```

If you are trying to connect NiFi on your local Windows system to remote Hadoop nodes, you will need the core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml from your Hadoop cluster, and since you have kerberos enabled you will need the krb5.conf file from one of your Hadoop servers (/etc/krb5.conf).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I set the JAVA_HOME path for jdk1.8.0_40 and now nifi is running succesfully on Hadoop cluster